# mysqli_fetch_array() foreach loop duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, foreach

I'm performing a request on a database which returns an `array`. I'm using a `foreach` loop to go through the values.

**Database** (only 1 entry)

```
id | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5
---|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------
1  | value1 |        | value3 | value4 | value5
```

**PHP Source code**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$q = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM my_table");

echo "<ul>";
    while($q = mysqli_fetch_array($q))
    {
        foreach ($q as $key => $value)
        {
            if($value != NULL)
            {
                echo "<li>".$value . "</li>";

                // Line below used to show column name and corresponding value
                //echo "<li><strong>{$key}</strong> / <em>{$value}</em></li>";
            }
        }
    }
echo "</ul>";
```

**Expected HTML output**

```
<ul>
    <li>value1</li>
    <li>value3</li>
    <li>value4</li>
    <li>value5</li>
</ul>
```

**Current output**

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>value1</li>
    <li>value1</li>
    <li>value3</li>
    <li>value3</li>
    <li>value4</li>
    <li>value4</li>
    <li>value5</li>
    <li>value5</li>
</ul>
```

**Current issue**

As you can see, I current have everything in double, and for some wierd reason, I'm getting the row ID, or so I assume considering I do not get a second row when I add a new row to the database.

**Alternate code**

Using the commented line, I get this output:

```
<ul>
    <li>0 / 1</li>
    <li>id / 1</li>
    <li>1 / value1</li>
    <li>field1 / value1</li>
    <li>3 / value3</li>
    <li>field3 / value3</li>
    <li>4 / value4</li>
    <li>field4 / value4</li>
    <li>5 / value5</li>
    <li>field5 / value5</li>
</ul>
```

**From what I understand**

- A `while` loop would allow me to go through each row from the database.
- A `foreach` loop is similar to a `while` loop, but instead of going through database entries, it goes through the key/value pairs from an `array`.

*(Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong about these previous statements.)*

**Thinking outloud**

- I'm starting to wonder, as I write this question, if the `while` and `foreach` seem kind of redundant in that both seem would parse the values, probably causing my duplicates...?
- Wouldn't the row number (in this case `1`) be a key?

Comment: Maybe it is because $q being set as the mysqli_query and also being set during the while?  Maybe try `while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($q))` ?

Comment: This produces the same result, ie twice the same output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns both an Associative Array (`$key => $value`) and a Numeric Array (`0 => value`), which is why you're getting duplicates - some of the entries have the column name as the key, the others have a numeric index.

If you want an associative array, you could use:

```
 mysqli_fetch_array($q, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 //or
 mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
```

Or for a numeric array:

```
 mysqli_fetch_array($q, MYSQLI_NUM);
 //or
 mysqli_fetch_row($q);
```

For more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php